# V4L buffer doesn't get cleaned properly

Tags: video, ffmpeg, camera, v4l

I've been trying to write a c program to capture photos from a uvc camera using v4l. I've managed to gt it to work for the most part but every second time i run the program i get a zero-filled yuv buffer which results in a "blank" green image. I tried capturing video using ffmpeg and i get similar results. Every second time i run the ffmpeg command `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video2 video.mp4`, i get a warning that says `[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x5567c2266f80] Dequeued v4l2 buffer contains corrupted data (0 bytes).` and the video is unplayable. If i cancel the capture at that point and remove and re-add the `uvcvideo` kernel module, everything works fine.

EDIT: every time i get a blank image there's a `uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Non-zero status (-71) in video completion handler.` dmesg log.

How can i solve that issue?

Thanks in advance